# Best way to build Breadcrumb Menu in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, user-controls, panel, breadcrumbs

I have a VB10 app that uses panels, one for menu, one for main screen and then i want to add one for a breadcrumb menu. I use user controls to display in pnlMain and would like the breadcrumb trail to add an link with user control info every time I add a screen to pnlmain...and remove the link when I click on the previous link.

I would like to build the links dynamically like they do here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17714/Create-a-Breadcrumb-Menu-in-VB-NET-WinForms,

but I couldnt get the links to display when I ran the solution.

and if I get the links to show, how do I associate the user control to that link?

Thank you for your help. The breadcrumb shouldnt go more than 3-4 levels deep

Comment: If I was doing it, I would create a user control that contained a `FlowLayoutPanel`.  The FLP would manage layout of the links and I'd have a property that exposed a collection of objects that each had a `Text` and a `Url` property.

Comment: I was able to get the link labels to show up dynamically like in  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17714/Create-a-Breadcrumb-Menu-in-VB-NET-WinForms.  It just adds links when a button is hit and removes it if the link before it is clicked. I need to be able to assign the link information about the user control that is displayed. How do I call a function with the user control as a parameter, so i can assign the user control to the link, so when they click it, it opens the user control?

Comment: I show the Usercontrol in a panel using the code:
<br/>
Dim tempobject As New ucSetup
pnlMain.Controls.Clear()
pnlMain.Controls.Add(tempobject)
<br/>
In the ItemClicked event of the breadcrumb usercontrol, how do I pass the usercontrol info to create the tempobject, so that I can put that uc in the pnlMain?  I was thinking of using the linklabel.tag, but it wont take a type usercontrol. Can I do type string and convert to a user control before dim tempobject as new [usercontrol]?

Comment: I show the Usercontrol in a panel using the code:  

Dim tempobject As New ucSetup
pnlMain.Controls.Clear()
pnlMain.Controls.Add(tempobject)  

In the ItemClicked event of the breadcrumb usercontrol, how do I pass the usercontrol info to create the tempobject, so that I can put that uc in the pnlMain?  I was thinking of using the linklabel.tag, but it wont take a type usercontrol. Can I do type string and convert to a user control before dim tempobject as new [usercontrol]?

Comment: You can assign anything you like to the `Tag` property of the `LinkLabel`.  In the `LinkClicked` event handler, use the `sender` parameter to access the `LinkLabel` that was clicked and then get the data back from its `Tag` to use how you see fit.  You could also derive your own class from `LinkLabel` and add your own property(ies) specifically for the data you need, then use that instead of a standard `LinkLabel`.